# React-Native Proxy being ignored in package.json

Tags: typescript, react-native, proxy

I have a react-native app and server and am trying a very basic get/fetch to confirm it's set up properly.

If I do `fetch('http://localhost:5000/api')` it works fine, but `fetch('/api')` fails.

I've confirmed that if I hit `http://localhost:5000/api` in the browser, I can see the API request, and I can hit the endpoint from Postman. It also doesn't appear to be making it to the server, as I have a console.log() that isn't being hit there in the case of `/api`.

Client package.json

```
  "name": "typescripttestproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.14",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
  },
```

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


app.use(express.json());
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    console.log('sending data from /api...')
    res.send({data: 'Hello World!'})
})

app.listen(5000, ()=> {console.log("Server started on port 5000...")})
```

Client page

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { ILoginProps } from './NavigationProps';

const Login = ({navigation}: ILoginProps) => { 
    return (
        <View>
            <Button title='Get Data'
            onPress={()=> {
                console.log('fetching...');

                //Does work
                fetch('http://localhost:5000/api')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => console.log(data));

                //Does not work
                fetch('/api')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => console.log(data));
            }}/>

            <Button 
            title='To Home'
            onPress={()=> {
                navigation.navigate('App');
            }}/>
        </View>
    );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: Does the client run in a browser? If so, what port does it run on?

Comment: Client running on port 3000, and runs on physical android device. I've also done `adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000` so that it's not getting confused about where localhost points too.

Comment: Well that should explain it. When you run fetch ("/api"), a request is made to http://localhost:3000/api, which is not where the endpoint is. The endpoint resides on http://localhost:5000/api, right?

Comment: If the proxy in package.json is localhost:5000, wouldn't /api point to localhost:5000/api? That's my understanding of how the proxy works at least, which I accept may be completely wrong. If that's the case, how can I make that connection over to port 5000 so I can  just put /api in the fetch?